# How does MobileNet v1 achieve small parameter count on tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

### Problem

I was trying to re-build [MobileNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04861) model identical to the [keras application provided version](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/MobileNet) on Tensorflow v2.1.0.

However, no matter what I tried (i.e., Conv2d, SeparableConv2D, DepthwiseConv2D), the parameter count seems way off to a point the model starts allocating 100+ GB ram in the system.

The model summary for the keras version and my own version along with the layers for my version could be found below under snippets section.

For sake of simplicity, I am not using any width and resolution multiplier (or let's say both has the value 1.0).

### Question

How might I achieve the same parameter count as low as the keras provided version?

### Snippets

#### Portion of keras mobilenet model summary

```
Model: "mobilenet_1.00_224"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)    (None, 225, 225, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 112, 112, 32)      864       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_bn (BatchNormalization (None, 112, 112, 32)      128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_relu (ReLU)            (None, 112, 112, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_1 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 112, 112, 32)      288       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_1_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 112, 112, 32)      128
```

### Portion of self created model summary

```
Model: "dummy_model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d (ZeroPadding2 (None, 225, 225, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 112, 112, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 112, 112, 32)      128       
_________________________________________________________________
re_lu (ReLU)                 (None, 112, 112, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
depthwise_conv2d (DepthwiseC (None, 112, 112, 32)      32800     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 112, 112, 32)      128
```

#### Self created model with layers

```
inputs = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=((1, 0), (1, 0)))(inputs)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="valid")(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = ReLU()(x)
x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x)
x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x, 2)
x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x)
x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x, 2)
x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x)
x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x, 2)

x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x)
x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x)
x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x)
x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x)
x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x)

x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x, 2)
x = depthwise_separable_convolution(x, 2)

x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=7)(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)

return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x, name="dummy_model")
```

#### Depthwise separable convolution

```
def depthwise_separable_convolution(self, input, strides=1):
    input_depth = input.shape[-1]
    output_depth = input_depth * 2

    x = DepthwiseConv2D(input_depth, 1, padding="same")(input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = ReLU()(x)
    x = Conv2D(output_depth, 1, padding="same")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = ReLU()(x)

    return x
```

Comment: First of all, you're adding bias to the filters, that's why you have difference of 32 between 896 for your model and 864 for their model for the Conv2D. Second, first input of DepthwiseConv2D is kernel size which is supposed to be $3 \times 3$, but you are providing depth of the previous layer, so you are making $32 \times 32$ kernels. You are also providing strides parameter to your function, but you're not using it anywhere, might want to fix that

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! This is just a programming/engineering issue, so it's off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. I will migrate this question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Brale_ thanks. your suggestion fixed the problem

Comment: @Brale - That looks like an answer.  If you took 2 minutes you could make this an answered question instead of one that looks unanswered except for the comments. ;)